# Make border colour depend on the position in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I have the following figure:
[image]

I want to make the colour of the border depend on the position. Specifically, for x < 5 the border of the top triangle should be black, and for x >= 5 the border should be red. In the end I want it to look like this:

[image]

The black lines are from Paint, of course. These pictures were made with the following code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}[
      xmin=-10,
      xmax=10,
      ymin=-10,
      ymax=10,
   ]

   \addplot[fill=lightgray, draw=red]
   table[row sep=crcr] {
   x    y\\
   -8 5\\
   9 9\\
   3 -7\\
   }--cycle;

   \addplot[fill=lightgray, draw=black]
   table[row sep=crcr] {
   x    y\\
   -9 -9\\
   9 -9\\
   0 -7\\
   }--cycle;
   \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

My actual figures are contour plots from matlab2tikz, and the code is way too long to post here. Is there an easy way to do this with pgfplots?

Comment: Do you want this for just one tikz-picture or for several? Do you want this to be black for the whole frame (conditionally) or just partially (the color changes from black to red if x > 5)?

Comment: I want it for one tikz-picture, although this is a simplified version of the real one (that one is a contour plot generated by matlab2tikz). I want the change only for one \addplot. I added a picture to make it more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done quite easily using the `fillbetween` library of PGFPlots.
(There is a quite similar example in the [PGFPlots manual in section 5.7.3
on page 432 (v1.14)](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf#page=432).)

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{
        pgfplots.fillbetween,
    }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xmin=-10,
            xmax=10,
            ymin=-10,
            ymax=10,
        ]
            \addplot[
                fill=lightgray,
                postaction={
                    decorate,
                    draw=red,
                    very thick,
                },
                decoration={
                    soft clip,
                    soft clip path={
                        domain=5:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},
                    },
                },
            ] table {
                x   y
                -8  5
                9   9
                3   -7
            } --cycle;

            \addplot[
                fill=lightgray,
                draw=black,
            ] table {
                x   y
                -9  -9
                9   -9
                0   -7
            } --cycle;
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]